# Writing a kama sutra cipher

Tags: cryptography

I took up cryptography recently, and 1 of my task was to create a kama sutra cipher. Up till the point of generating the keys, I will have no problems. However, due to the nature of kama sutra, I believe that the keys are not supposed to be hard coded into the program, but rather generated for each plain text it takes in.

What I understand is that the cipher text's length should be the same as the length of plain text. However, the thing is that where do I place the key, such that as long as the cipher text is generated by my program, the program would be able to decipher it even if the program was closed. Given that this is an algorithm, I am sure that I should not be looking at storing the key in another flat file/ database.

There are not many related information online regarding this cipher. What I saw are those that allow you to randomise a key set, generate a cipher text based on the given key set. When decrypting, you will also need to provide the same key set. Is this the correct way of implementation?

For those who have knowledge about this, please guide me along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to decrypt the cyphertext, then you need to be able to recover the key whenever you need.  For a classical cypher, this was usually done by using the same key for multiple messages, see the Caesar Cypher for an example.  Caesar used a constant key, a -3/+3 shift while Augustus used a +1/-1 shift.

You may want to consult your instructor as to whether a fixed key or a varying key is required.

It will be simpler to develop a fixed key version, and then to add varying key functionality on top.  That way you can get the rest of the program working correctly.

You may also want to look at classical techniques for using a keyphrase to mix an alphabet.

Comment: I don't think that my lecturer will be interested in a fixed key. I have just been tasked to decrypt vignere cipher and monoalphabetic cipher by hand, hence for this task, we will have to encrypt and decrypt a plain text with kama sutra cipher. I would not have problem if it is fixed, since it is hardcoding :) Currently I'm pretty stuck on how to make my key varying yet not storing it.

Comment: Look at my last sentence.  See also the description and example in Wikipedia's article on the Playfair cipher.

Comment: hmm, keyphrase.non repeating letter keyphrase in a random index + remainder of letters used like how a keyphrase cipher is used? Possible? Mind guiding slightly more? Playfair can wait, I have another task given to me to use playfair algorithm.

Comment: You have it. Remove repeats from the keyphrase, and then add the remaining letters in order.  This is homework, so I'm not going to help you more than that.

Comment: That will be enough for the clarification. Time to do the real job. :)